# Text label hides behind the circle node in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

```js
function drawGraph(theGraph) {

  var width = 1500,
    height = 900;

  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-480)
    .linkDistance(120)
    .size([width, height]);

  var svg2 = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("top", "0").style("left", "0").style("position", "absolute");

  var svg = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("top", "0").style("left", "0").style("position", "absolute");

  force
    .links(theGraph.links)
    .nodes(theGraph.nodes)
    .start();

  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(theGraph.nodes).enter().append('g').classed('node', true);

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .call(force.drag);

  increaseNodeSize(node, calculateNodeLinks(theGraph));
  link = svg2.selectAll(".link")
    .data(theGraph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')';
    })
  });

  node.on("mouseover", function(d) { // When mouse over a node, the labels are being appended; however some of the labels hide behind the circle.
    d3.select(this).classed('hovered', true)
      .append("text").classed('label', true).classed('hover', true).text(function(d) {
        return d.name
      });

    seq.state("mouseovered", d.name);

    var neighborNodes = [];
    link.filter(function(l) {
      if (l.source === d) {
        if ($.inArray(l.target.name, neighborNodes) == -1) {
          neighborNodes.push(l.target.name);
          return true;
        }
      }
      if (l.target === d) {
        if ($.inArray(l.source.name, neighborNodes) == -1) {
          neighborNodes.push(l.source.name);
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }).classed('highlighted', true);

    node.filter(function(d) {
        return $.inArray(d.name, neighborNodes) > -1
      }).classed('highlighted', true)
      .append("text").classed('label', true).text(function(d) {
        return d.name
      });

  });

  node.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    seq.state("mouseovered", "");
    node.selectAll("text").remove();
    d3.select(this).classed('hover', false);
    link.classed("highlighted", false);
  });

}
```

The problem is when i mouse over the circle nodes, some of the text labels hide behind the circle. How can i resolve this ?[image: Force graph layout]. I have tried through the z index(css), but still it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Just a suggestion, not sure if it will work. Try `overflow:visible` via css on the text element

Comment: There is no z-index in SVG.

Comment: Overflow suggestion does not work.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, even if i add 'g' element before appending the text label to the node, it still does not work for me.

Comment: Bostock's explanation is very clear. In your case, it doesn't work because you're appending the text to the same group that contains the node. Obviously, that won't work. You'll have to refactor all your mouseover function... I suggest you post a new question asking how to refactor the mouseover. That way, the question won't be a duplicate, as this one is.